# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blurr.data'

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm trying to follow this site to fine-tune BERT.

https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-tuning-the-bart-large-model-for-text-summarization-3c69e4c04582

I installed **blurr** successfully with this code:

```
!pip install ohmeow-blurr -q
```

But when I executed this code I get an error

```
from blurr.data.all import *
```

The error is:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blurr.data'

Any solution!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from blurr.text.data.all import *

Then Delete BLURR word
```

Comment: Thank you @Sulisetyo it works, but I have another error with this intruction `hf_arch, hf_config, hf_tokenizer, hf_model = BLURR.get_hf_objects(pretrained_model_name, model_cls=BartForConditionalGeneration)`  which is **NameError: name 'BLURR' is not defined**. Any suggestion!!

Comment: I solve it, I just delete the word **BLURR** and it works.

Comment: Good jobs ..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the module is in your path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).